How to establish trust relationship for WCF SSL/TLS Secure Channel
We have client server application where its using WCF for the communication. How to correctly associate a certificate to a WCF Service using app.config. Right now I am defining the certificate in the app.config as follows on the server;
   <behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
<serviceCredentials>
<serviceCertificate findValue="5b92cf508b894aec82074514954185ecd78b654a" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
</serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
</behaviors>

In the client side, I am assigning the certificate programmatically as follows,
   X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "5b92cf508b894aec82074514954185ecd78b654a", true); //I am seeing the certificate correctly. Please see the screenshot below.

            InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
            this.SystemService = new SystemServiceClient(context, tcpBinding, tcpAddress);
            this.SystemService.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificates[0];

When debugging it correctly shows the certificate as follows on the client side,

When trying to establish a connection with the WCF service using the line string[] lstIFs = this.ServerConnection.NetworkService.GetNetworkInterfaces();, we get an error as follows, 'System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority'.

Edit
Here is the stack trace for the exception
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

   at EchoAdminClient.SystemService.INetworkSettingService.GetNetworkInterfaces()

   at EchoAdminClient.SystemService.NetworkSettingServiceClient.GetNetworkInterfaces() in C:\Git\EchoAdminForEcho65XPlus\EchoAdminClient\Connected Services\SystemService\Reference.cs:line 843

   at EchoAdminClient.MainForm.UpdateNetworkSettings() in C:\Git\EchoAdminForEcho65XPlus\EchoAdminClient\MainForm.cs:line 556

   at EchoAdminClient.MainForm.ConnectServer() in C:\Git\EchoAdminForEcho65XPlus\EchoAdminClient\MainForm.cs:line 495

And the Data and the inner exception are as follows:
Data: "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost:8080'."

Type: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException

Inner Exception:
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Type: System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

If we examine further, there is an other inner exception that says,
{"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."}

Type: System.Exception {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException}

Here is the screenshot of the certificate:


Sounds like it's the server certificate that's the problem, the client is rejecting it (probably because it's either self-signed, or the name localhost doesn't match the SAN in the certificate). Please show the full error message along with the stack trace. Please do not post images of code or data or errors, only paste as text.

@Charlieface can you please look at the edits for the question.

Yes I was right, it's a self-signed server certificate, so the client doesn't trust it. See the answer below. I don't really understand the point of using client certificates if you blindly use a self-signed certificate: does it make sense that the client always trusts the server but the server does not trust the client?

@Charlieface We are trying to perform feasibility to enable HTTPS on our WCF and we want to make sure it works with a self signed certificate before purchasing one.

Since you can display the certificate correctly on the client, I think it could be that the client thinks this certificate is not secure and it doesn't trust this key.
Here are some suggestions you can take:
1.Use makecert to create a root CA and create a certificate from it
2.Use a Windows Certificate Server or other PKI solution that then trusts that root certificate
3.Buy an SSL certificate from a CA.
Of course, you can also add the following code to ignore the server certificate:
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
        new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
            RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };


I have tried the following. Can you look at the edits for the post. When I try the code snipper you gave, it gives an error saying "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'." And the type is "System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException". In the InnerException it says "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden".

@nikhil That is an entirely different question. If you are getting 403 it means the TLS connection is fine, it's just the normal HTTP authentication not happening. Possibly you need IIS Certificate Mapping if you are using client certificates, so that it can authenticate from the certificate information.

I think you should add your certificate as a trusted certificate. That way there will be no warnings. You can refer to this post as follows: How to accept a self-signed SSL certificate in a WCF client?
